# Class cannot be accessed outside package - camera2 CameraCharacteristics.Key

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am using Camera2 api, and I am unable to construct a Key to look up
For example

```
public static CameraCharacteristics.Key<Byte> IS_SUPPORT_QCFA_SENSOR =
        new CameraCharacteristics.Key<>("org.codeaurora.qcamera3.quadra_cfa.is_qcfa_sensor", Byte.class);
```

Causes the message

```
'Key(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class<T>)' is not public in 'android.hardware.camera2.CameraCharacteristics.Key'. Cannot be accessed from outside package
```

But in order to look up a Key, they have to be constructed. The documentation on developer.android.com says it is

```
public static final class CameraCharacteristics.Key
```

How can I construct a Key? Or Fix this problem?

Comment: What target sdk version do you have? I had the same problem for api level <= 28. I believe that you can construct a key from api version 29.

Comment: Yeah, also a pain since vendor specific keys exist on version 28 and even lower. Ive got part of what I want working. But am unable to get a raw image (reported as supported).

Answer (score 0):

Was recently looking at something similar found this. Take a look at the sample from :

https://github.com/dragonGR/packages_apps_SnapdragonCamera/blob/1c35bb80c3abfe6a7c5212572aa8abbeb9850eb2/src/com/android/camera/util/VendorTagUtil.java

They use CaptureRequest not CameraCharacteristics to define keys and can be access once the cameradevice is defined.

Might be worth trying it that way instead, the link has more details.

```
private static CaptureRequest.Key<Integer> CdsModeKey =
        new CaptureRequest.Key<>("org.codeaurora.qcamera3.CDS.cds_mode",
                Integer.class);

and

private static boolean isSupported(CaptureRequest.Builder builder,
                                   CaptureRequest.Key<?> key) {
    boolean supported = true;
    try {
        builder.get(key);
    }catch(IllegalArgumentException exception){
        supported = false;
        Log.d(TAG, "vendor tag " + key.getName() + " is not supported");
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( supported ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "vendor tag " + key.getName() + " is supported");
    }
    return supported;
}
```